# Is my redux state variable vulnerable to be extracted by an angry employee? No api calls or AsyncStorage

Tags: security, react-native, redux, state, react-navigation

I made a react native app(redux, xcode, react-navigation) to assess certain things for medical patients. There is a patient name, patient id, doctor name, and visit date getting saved for a short period of time in a reducer, created in a component's component level state, and pulled into a couple additional components, it then gets cleared by returning the app home, or when the app gets closed out I assume because it is not saved in asyncstorage. There is no api call whatsoever in the app. But if an angry employee has the knowledge that this redux state variable can be extracted, and has the access to an ipad when that data is created, attempts to extract it, how possible is it? How long would it take to extract? Naturally i am concerned that there is a possibility this object can be extracted, and if it is, how can i make it as difficult as possible in that nearly impossible scenario(nearly impossible for undisclosed reasons)?

Comment: I'm not super familiar with react-native but I think most apps have some kind of live debugging ability, in which case it would be super easy to extract since almost everything in the app is going to hit the store somewhere.. then `store.getState()` and you have everything. You should add the ability to manually clear the data, or clear it in a timer if idle for some amount of time

Comment: @azium Ah! Thank you for responding to my post, I forgot to mention that i saw on the main react native documentation site that the devtools gets turned off in production. I would love a confirmation on that though as i am a 1 year+ bootcamp developer.

Comment: 'There is no api call whatsoever in the app.' Doesn't that mean the doctor's name etc is hard coded into the app somewhere? 

'has the access to an ipad when that data is created' Does this mean they have access to the ipad that created the data? If so, why?

As a general rule, don't provide _anything_ to a react app that the user shouldn't be seeing. Assume they have access to everything you serve them.

Comment: @crowhill -The doctor’s name gets entered into a form and then saved as mentioned. It can be a different doctor.

-They would have the ipad itself, not access to the data directly, they would have to break in to the ipad to get the data after receiving the ipad back from the patient. The results are printed with react-native-print, and scanned by the office worker(s) into the medical records. It seems like my liability is pretty dang small because a worker can take that paper and it is not my app’s fault.

Comment: Okay, all of that more or less makes sense. I can't say anything about the liability, or how much it matters in this situation, but anything created or stored client side is _not_ secure from a determined attacker.

Comment: @crowhill Is there anything i can do to make it more difficult?

Comment: @crowhill The company about to launch my app used a different ipad app for the same function. They likely had a front end with tokens. Is it worth it to save/update/ and then destroy this one variable on a safe server?

Comment: Making things "more difficult" is a bad solution if the contents should not be reachable by an attacker. Your online banking password is not "secure enough" because it's "more difficult", it's secure because it's sent over https, encrypted on the server's disk and certainly is not retained in state after logging in. If this is an ipad that is shared amongst staff and the contents should not be leaked, then you need to enforce each staff member logs in / out to retrieve only information that is available to them.

Comment: I don't know of a way to for an app to issue itself tokens, if that's what you're asking. Security-through-obscurity isn't necessarily a bad idea, but security-through-security should come first. I can say from first hand experience that HIPPA/PHI data breaches are no joke.

Comment: @crowhill Not issue itself tokens, connect to a server to save the one medical data variable and then delete because it’s no longer needed. Like google firebase for example.

Comment: I was going off of this quote: "There is no api call whatsoever in the app."

If you can star utilizing outside services, then, by all means, do so. Storing the information somewhere outside of the app is the way to go.

Comment: @azium The iPads are used for this one and only purpose in the offices, they are not passed around per se, and are not for personal use. Also this information is seen and used by an RN in the office. This data can be walked out of the building after it gets printed. It seems the worker would steal that instead of hacking into the ipad no?

Comment: @crowhill Then will I be susceptible to an attack between the server and client? Or the encryption and web tokens prevents and detects it? Thank you for your help btw.

Comment: your server will need an TLS cert and you send all of your data over HTTPS. then as long as the server is properply encypting the data before putting it into the databse then you'll be mostly fine

Comment: @azium Thank you for your help.